# If we think thoughts about consciousness with the mind, does it imply mind is aware of consciousness?

Tags: consciousness, mind

We think everything in our minds. Even when one talks about pure consciousness he is referring to one's own thoughts which are products of mind. Now consciousness is the changeless perception of these changing thoughts. When one talks about consciousness, the mind which is forming thoughts about consciousness, must necessarily be aware of consciousness in the first place right?

In other words, how is the mind able to form coherent thoughts and logic about something, if it's not aware of it? Does this imply that consciousness has causal powers over the mind, causing it to think whatever consciousness wants? But consciousness cannot want anything because it is a perception of "wanting" itself. So how is it even possible to talk/think about consciousness if the mind is like a mechanical bull driving the cart we call our body? The charioteer is the consciousness within us.

If mind thinks about consciousness, then what is really happening? Are we saying that our minds do whatever they like and our consciousness simply observes? But that would imply that we don't have free will, only the mind has free will. Even if we grant the mind free will, how does the mind form a thought about that which observes it? Isn't the mind an object of observation? So how can an object of observation think about the process of observation?

Comment: In some contexts consciousness means "not being asleep." I'm used to discussing it as "the awareness that rests behind most other aspects of the self." For example, we have different personas for different people in the "external world" such as one for your grandmother & one for your best friend. Behind that is ego desire/cravings, the thinker of thoughts, the emoter of emotions, memory, etc. Behind these is awareness. One can be aware of their thoughts/emotions/memories as well as the external world. Behind that the the experiencer of existence.

Comment: So, by this model, yes my awareness can be aware of my thoughts even when those thoughts are thinking about the awareness or the aspect of self in charge of it. The awareness is configured such that it can access (be aware of) the thoughts. Those thoughts, however, do not have access to the awareness itself. The thoughts are only manipulating the thinker's **conceptualization** of awareness. Hopefully this answered your question, but please explain what is difficult, if not. Unfortunately I cannot make a proper Answer because the question isn't clearly about Hinduism

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī so the thinker is manipulating what shall be become aware of?

Comment: IMO, the awareness is aware of all things—including that which is not. But the specific part of awareness that I consider "my awareness" is only aware of that which it has been brought to its attention. As infants, when a ball rolls behind the sofa, we believe that the ball is gone from existence. This specific consciousness is not yet well developed. If one surrounds onesself with wiser people, becomes exposed to new ways of thinking, different cultures, unexpected ideas, etc, one will have a very expansive awareness.

Comment: Attention leads to thoughts. Thoughts lead to words. Words to actions. Actions to habits. Habits to a life. Having experienced much, one can then refine the things one keeps in their mind. Some choose to focus on ego desires. Some choose to focus on how they feel. Some choose to focus on solving puzzles. Some choose to focus on the divine. In my experience, most people do not realize they can choose where to focus their awareness.

Comment: It just struck me that, perhaps rather than wondering about the awareness you want to know about "the decider." I can let my ego run amok or I can decide to listen to the still, small voice that connects me to divinity. I can decide where to focus awareness. I cannot decide my thoughts or emotions. Those seem to be the results of cause & effect. I have not previously thought about where this decider resides or what exactly it is—so thank you for this chance. It seems to me that it is the single most important factor for individuation. Something which makes the One seems as many.